# Is Python DataStax driver for Cassandra threadsafe?

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

so far it doesn't seem to be.

We have a Pyramid service that is writing and reading to and fro to Cassandra.  I notice if I run the unit test suite and then simultaneously try to run something else against the service - it all comes crashing down.

I'm using cassandra-driver 3.6.0 and Cassandra 2.2.6

Thanks for info

Comment: Can you provide more on what "doesn't seem to be" means? Low effort response to question is "Yes" but I dont know what your doing that seems to be issue. Theres some things you can do if using API in unexpected way that may cause issues.

Comment: Per edit: Cassandra is eventually consistent. If you make reads directly after writes and expect to see it, but don't tune your consistency level you may get weird issues. "Crashing down" is too vague, can you elaborate? It is thread safe (dont have 2 threads reading same result set though) so there may be something else going on.